# GLSL: gl_FragCoord issues

Tags: opengl-es, coordinates, glsl, shader

I am experimenting with GLSL for OpenGL ES 2.0. I have a quad and a texture I am rendering. I can successfully do it this way:

```
//VERTEX SHADER
attribute highp vec4 vertex;
attribute mediump vec2 coord0;

uniform mediump mat4 worldViewProjection;

varying mediump vec2 tc0;

void main()
{
    // Transforming The Vertex
    gl_Position = worldViewProjection * vertex;

    // Passing The Texture Coordinate Of Texture Unit 0 To The Fragment Shader
    tc0 = vec2(coord0);
}

//FRAGMENT SHADER
varying mediump vec2 tc0;

uniform sampler2D my_color_texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(my_color_texture, tc0);
}
```

So far so good. However, I'd like to do some pixel-based filtering, e.g. Median. So, I'd like to work in pixel coordinates rather than in normalized (`tc0`) and then convert the result back to normalized coords. Therefore, I'd like to use `gl_FragCoord` instead of a uv attribute (`tc0`). But I don't know how to go back to normalized coords because I don't know the range of gl_FragCoords. Any idea how I could get it? I have got that far, using a fixed value for 'normalization', though it's not working perfectly as it is causing stretching and tiling (but at least is showing something):

```
//FRAGMENT SHADER
varying mediump vec2 tc0;

uniform sampler2D my_color_texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(my_color_texture, vec2(gl_FragCoord) / vec2(256, 256));
}
```

So, the simple question is, what should I use in the place of `vec2(256, 256)` so that I could get the same result as if I were using the uv coords.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

gl_FragCoord is in screen coordinates, so to get normalized coords you need to divide by the viewport width and height. You can use a uniform variable to pass that information to the shader, since there is no built in variable for it.

Comment: Thanks! Umm, could I get the viewport size from within the shader?

Comment: @Albus Nope,as i said, the only way is passing it manually via a uniform variable.

Comment: Thanks. If it's not too much of a bother, could you just give me an idea of how to pass the variable from outside of my shader. You see, I am very new to OpenGL. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can also sample the texture by un-normalized coordinates if:

- sampling by texture() from GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE
- sampling by texelFetch() from a regular texture or texture buffer

Comment: Thanks, but is it valid in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore. Sorry, it doesn't apply to GL ES at all. My answer is useless for you.

Comment: No worries. It's always better to know more even if it isn't exactly what one was looking for. Thanks :-)