# Usage of gl_FragCoord for monitors with different DPIs

Tags: opengl, screen-resolution, fragment-shader

What is the proper way to account for the different DPIs of monitors writing a fragment shader? I am using glFragCoord to make things only display on part of the screen. Things display as indented on my external monitor (taking up the whole of my small GL window) and incorrectly on my built in monitor (scaled down to take only the bottom left quarter of the window). Is there a cross platform way to resolve this kind of issue?

I am pretty sure that this is the right diagnosis of my problem because my shader looks different on my built in display (15.4 inch 2880x1800) and on my external (22 inch 1680x1050). Has anyone run into this?

Comment: Pass the viewport size with an uniform and work in normalized coordinates. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144793/glsl-gl-fragcoord-issues.

Comment: I am telling it to use the same viewport size for each, that is, I'm specifying it in pixels. Also, I just realized that coordinates that are passed into the vertex shader are mapped correctly, it's only things that are determined entirely within the fragment shader that are wrong. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Also, the program doesn't know when I am dragging between monitors, so it shouldn't make a difference what number I'm passing it if that number isn't changing.

Comment: If you specify a viewport size that is smaller than the window you are rendering in, you get only the bottom left part. You should set the viewport size to be the same as the window size. That or I did not understand  the problem.

Comment: I don't feel like I asked it extremely clearly. My takeaway from this is that gl_fragCoord is not a great way to provide a positional reference and that it will be better to work with points in the same coordinate system as they were passed into the vertex shader--so just pass them from the vertex shader to the fragment shader.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but I still don't feel like I really have a great grip on the problem. Because the vertex shader is being used correctly, I just pass the position to the fragment shader as a 'varying' rather than using gl_fragCoord. It interpolates on its way to the fragment shader and it seems to take the differences between the monitors into account. It's still in clip space, so you have to transform it accordingly.